# Proving by induction for $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Question: Prove that for any nonnegative integer $n$, $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$.

So I suppose that $n^3 - n = 3m$ for some integer $m$.

I know it is true for $n= 1$.

Suppose it is true for $n=k$. So $k^3 - k = 3t$ for some integer $t$.

How to prove it for $n= k+1$? I didn't get the equation for $n= k+1$.

Comment: Did you write out $(k+1)^3-(k+1)$, which you want to be divisible by $3$, and compare it with$k^3-k$, which you already know i divisible by 3?

Comment: This is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for $p=3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(k+1)^3 - (k+1) = k^3 +3k^2+3k+1 - k - 1

```
            = (k^3 - k) + 3k^2 + 3k

            = 3t + 3(k^2 + k)

            = 3(t + k^2 + k) which is divisible by 3 
                             since (t+ k^2+k)i s integer
```

it is hold for n= k+1

Answer (score -1):

Assume it's true that $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$.  Then

\begin{eqnarray}
(n+1)^3 - (n+1)  & = & (n+1)\left [(n+1)^2 - 1\right ] \\
 & = & (n+1)\left [ n^2 + 2n\right ] \\
 & = & n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n \\
 & = & \left (n^3 - n\right ) + 3\left (n^2 + n\right ).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score -1):

Note: $n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=n(n-1)(n+1);$

Base case:

$n=1√$

Hypothesis:

$n(n-1)(n+1)$ is divisible by $3$.

Step for $n+1$:

$(n+1)(n)(n+2) =$

$n(n+1)((n-1)+3)=$

$n(n+1)(n-1) +3n(n+1).$

The first term is divisible by $3$ by hypothesis, the second term is a multiple of $3$, their sum is divisible by $3$.